# Es posible mostrar notificaciones con icono personalizado en Windows 10 con Java?

Tags: java, interfaz-gráfica

Se como hacer para que se muestre este tipo de notificaciones:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero resulta que solo cambia el icono al cambiar el tipo de mensaje:

```
trayIcon.displayMessage("Titulo", "Contenido", TrayIcon.MessageType.INFO);
```

Es lo unico que yo he podido encontrar en internet, Ustedes tienen alguna idea de que podria hacer?

Aqui dejo el code del TrayIcon con el que uso el displayMessage():

```
public void IconoBandeja(){

    if(!SystemTray.isSupported()){
        System.out.println("We can't show the Tray Icon");
    }

    final PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu();
    trayIcon = new TrayIcon(CreateIcon("/img/logo.jpg", "Administrador de clientes"));
    trayIcon.setImageAutoSize(true);
    final SystemTray tray = SystemTray.getSystemTray();
    //trayIcon.setToolTip("Version 1.6.21\nProject Jarvis");

    //Add components/ Menu items
    MenuItem AboutItem = new MenuItem("About");
    MenuItem ExitItem = new MenuItem("Exit");

    //Populate the pop up menu
    popup.add(AboutItem);
    popup.addSeparator();
    popup.add(ExitItem);

    trayIcon.setPopupMenu(popup);

    AboutItem.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
    {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
        {
            trayIcon.displayMessage("Titulo", "Contenido", TrayIcon.MessageType.INFO);
        }
    });

    try 
    {
        tray.add(trayIcon);
    }catch (AWTException e) 
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Yo la única información que he podido sacar buscando, es que poniendo el mensaje de información a `NONE`, te pondrá como icono la imagen pasada como argumento al `TrayIcon` --- `TrayIcon.MessageType.NONE`

Comment: Wow haha, Es super raro.. Ya antes habia intentado con el NONE pero no se por que esta vez si funciono, Muchisimas gracias nuevamente Sr Diego, Eres grande! Si puedes publica la solucion para ponerla como respuesta correcta :)

Comment: Gracias a ti @Extibax. Sigue así :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Es posible mostrar notificaciones con icono personalizado - *TrayIcon*?

Poniendo tu tipo de mensaje a **NONE**, te pondrá como icono la imagen pasada como argumento al `TrayIcon`

```
TrayIcon.MessageType.NONE
```

La llamada completa al método `displayMessage` dentro del *actionPerformed*

```
trayIcon.displayMessage("Titulo", "Contenido", TrayIcon.MessageType.NONE);
```

---

Así se vería en mi caso particular..

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]